# Laravel relationship to a few columns with other tables

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relational-database

I have a question about relationship tables in Laravel. I have a table "revisions" wherein I have columns "old_value" and "new_value". This table stores the change history records. The problem is when i want return records with table "revision" on page. The return value is, example:

> "User Jack change name products from 1 to 2"

but I want to be the return value:

> "User Jack change name products from BALL to SHOES"

Is there a way to combine the relationship table "revision" of the table "products", "articles" and "categories". For example based on the value of the columns "revisionable_type" or "key". The problem is that to columns "old_value" and "new_value" saved is records from columns "article_id", "category_id" with table "products" and colums "id" with table "articles" and colums "id" with table "categories"

Screen table: "revision":http://iv.pl/images/78755893242784790812.png

Screen table: "products":http://iv.pl/images/82849082096359450147.png

Screen table: "articles":http://iv.pl/images/81440394780221859215.png

Screen table: "categories":http://iv.pl/images/03724618899545660879.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way out would be to query each id on the category table.

```
<div>User {{ $user }} change name products from 
{{ Category::whereId(*theId*)->first()->category_name }}
to
{{ Category::whereId(*theId*)->first()->category_name }}
</div>
```

Although, I think the real problem lies within your table structure. The old_value and new_value on Revisions table are relations to the category table. Try to find out more about how to normalize your tables.